# How to create a path using the Windows.Storage API?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

`System.IO.CreateDirectory()` is not available on .NET for Windows Store Apps.

How can I implement this equivalent method? `StorageFolder.CreateFolderAsync()` creates a subfolder inside the current folder, but in my case I have a path like and need to create all folders that doesn't exist in this path.

The path is inside the app's sandbox in windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no API with exactly the same behaviour of `System.IO.CreateDirectory()`, so I implemented it using `Windows.Storage` classes:

```
    // Any and all directories specified in path are created, unless they already exist or unless 
    // some part of path is invalid. If the directory already exists, this method does not create a 
    // new directory.
    // The path parameter specifies a directory path, not a file path, and it must in 
    // the ApplicationData domain.
    // Trailing spaces are removed from the end of the path parameter before creating the directory.
    public static void CreateDirectory(string path)
    {
         path = path.Replace('/', '\\').TrimEnd('\\');
        StorageFolder folder = null;

        foreach(var f in new StorageFolder[] {
            ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, 
            ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder, 
            ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder } )
        {
            string p = ParsePath(path, f);
            if (f != null)
            {
                path = p;
                folder = f;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(path == null)
            throw new NotSupportedException("This method implementation doesn't support " +
            "parameters outside paths accessible by ApplicationData.");

        string[] folderNames = path.Split('\\');
        for (int i = 0; i < folderNames.Length; i++)
        {
            var task = folder.CreateFolderAsync(folderNames[i], CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists).AsTask();
            task.Wait();
            if (task.Exception != null)
                throw task.Exception;
            folder = task.Result;
        }
    }

    private static string ParsePath(string path, StorageFolder folder)
    {
        if (path.Contains(folder.Path))
            {
                path = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf(folder.Path) + folder.Path.Length + 1);
                return path;
            }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: and what does ParsePath do?

Comment: ops I forgot about it. I've updated the answer. The project containing this code is supposed to get open-sourced this weekend, by the way. It's a reimplementation of a collection of classes that are now unsupported on WSA/WP8.

Answer (score 0):

To create folders outside your app's sandbox in windows store app, you'll have to add the document library in app-manifest, along with file permissions.

For a much more detailed explanation regarding library and documents, Refer [this](http://lunarfrog.com/blog/2011/10/03/winrt-storage-overview/) blog

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention this before, I have full access in the path, I want to know which API in the Windows namespace is more similar to the System.IO.CreateDirectory(), which API should I use to get the same functionality.

Comment: I think StorageFolder.CreateFolderAsync() API would be able to create folders if you have permissions.